# Is there a way to detect when an update panel is done refreshing?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, asp.net-3.5

Is there a way to detect when an update panel is done refreshing?  I want to fire some javascript methods when the update panel is finished.

Perhaps via the UpdateProgress control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
   // do what you want here
}
```

Of course, this will caputure every AJAX EndRequest call so you'll have to make your EndRequestHandler function see what has been requested or play with BeginRequestHandler. More info [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/PageRequestManagerOverview.aspx).