# Call a Javascript Function after UpdatePanel Postback Issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, dom-events, updatepanel

I basically have in my `UpdatePanel` a literal that generates a Javascript array based on a method in my codebehind.

I don't have an issue when it comes to loading my content on page load. But if I try and carry out a search to update my Javascript array literal within my `UpdatePanel`, I found that the literal gets updated on postback after the Javascript has already fired.

Here is a basic example of what I have:

```
<script type="text\javascript">
function BindMyFunction(itemList)
{
    //Do something
}
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>  
<!-- Literal containing generated JS array -->
    <asp:Literal ID="ProfileJavscriptOutput" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
    <ul id="person-search">
    <li><asp:TextBox ID="TxtFirstname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox></li>
    <!-- Update Literal onClick -->
        <li><asp:ImageButton CssClass="searchbtn" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" /></li>
    </ul>    
    <!-- Some jCarousel rendered -->
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've been looking at the following posts:

[ASP.NET - UpdatePanel and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418072/asp-net-updatepanel-and-javascript)

[call javascript after updatepanel postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941156/call-javascript-after-updatepanel-postback)

But I can't seem to apply it correctly to my code.

It works fine when I don't use an `UpdatePanel`. But it is a requirement so that the page position does not move when searches are carried out.

Comment: what does the code look like before and what does it look like after?

Comment: How is the JavaScript being called when the full page loads?

Comment: Didn't your mother ever tell you update panels are bad?

Comment: @Nick Yes I know. lol! But this is the only way I could think about doing a postback without refreshing the page in SharePoint.

Comment: it does refresh the page exactly like a post back, except you can't visually tell (except for the fact that responses aren't as fast as true AJAX calls).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can add the following code in Page_Load event:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.rptGridAlbum, rptGridAlbum.GetType, "scriptname", "somejavascript", True)
```

This will fire the javascript on your page after the AJAX callback.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

Comment: Yep that worked I basically called the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript on getting the initial data and then I called that when I carried out my searches to update the Javascript.

Comment: Too bad a better explanation of the arguments wasn't given otherwise this answer would probably have way more Up votes

Comment: If you're trying to include a whole javascript file note that the 4th parameter is not the path to the file, but the actual javascript contents.  You can do something like `File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Virtual/Path/To/File.js"))`

Comment: Although this works, it seems to build up progressive script bloat in the resulting document after multiple calls. However, there's another [idea here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/456223/314291)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple webservice method that returns the javascript array to the page whenever required and wrap the call to that webservice in a javascript method.  Invoking the javascript method to refresh the array in memory on the browser side will work better than expecting the js array literal to be parsed again on `UpdatePanel` postbacks with any success.

Comment: Updating a JS array on UpdatePanel postback is probably better done using [`ScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            DisplayCurrentTime(); // here your javascript function
        }
    });
};
```