# How to wait until an ASP.NET Multiview changes its ActiveViewIndex via PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, multiview

I am working in ASP.NET 3.5 with VB.NET as my server-side language.  I am using JavaScript via jQuery 1.5.2 as my client-side language.  I am trying to do a prototype / namespace setup with this page. This page is a custom logon page using MultiView.  I have a Policy Logon view and a Forgot Password view.  I am storing the ActiveViewIndex in a hidden field called `currentView`.

I'm using Partial Postbacks with the UpdatePanel in this project, and the JS doesn't get refreshed on the Partial PostBacks.

That said, I need a way to wait for the ActiveViewIndex to get changed server-side, so that I can call the `init()` function to the respective view. Is this possible?

My client side code:

## Global JS

---

```js
var page = 
{                   
    currentView : getContentElement( "currentView" ),
    
    init : function () 
    { 
        log( "initializing page" );
                            
        if ( this.currentView === "forgotpassword" ) { forgotPassword.init(); }
        else { policyLogon.init(); }    
    }
}; 

page.init();
```

## Policy Logon View JS

---

```js
var policyLogon = 
{                       
    panel              : getContentElement( "pnlLogonInfo", "div" ),
    submitButton       : getContentElement( "btnLogon", this.panel ),
    textInputs         : $( "input[ type=text ]", this.panel ),
    policyNumber       : getContentElement( "txtPolicyNumber", this.textInputs ),
    policyNumberError  : getContentElement( "lblPolicyNumberError", this.panel ),
    password           : getContentElement( "txtPassword", this.textInputs ),
    passwordError      : getContentElement( "lblPasswordError", this.panel ),
    forgotPasswordLink : getContentElement( "lbtnForgotPassword", this.panel ),
                    
    init : function () 
    { 
        log( "initializing policy logon" );
                        
        var that = this;

        // Other event handlers created here [redacted to keep example code short].

        that.forgotPasswordLink.on("click", function () 
        {
            // Code to wait for PostBack should go here.

            page.init();
        });

        that.policyNumber.focus();              
    }
};
```

## Forgot Password View JS

---

```js
var forgotPassword = 
{
                            
    // Local vars, set up the same way as Policy Logon, just different elements.
    // [redacted to keep example code short]
                        
    init : function () 
    { 
        log( "initializing forgot password" );
                            
        var that = this;
    
        // Other event handlers created here [redacted to keep example code short].
    
        that.policyNumber.focus();                      
    }    
};
```

---

As a preemptive strike against the what is `getContentElement()` questions, `getContentElement()` is a function I had to create due to nested master pages where elements will have to be called differently based on what master page they are using. It looks like this:

```js
function getContentElement ( id, context ) 
{ 
    var publicPrefix = csMasterPrefix + csContentPrefix,
        securePrefix = cpMasterPrefix + publicPrefix + cpContentPrefix,
        publicId = "#" + publicPrefix + id,
        secureId = "#" + securePrefix + id;
    
    return ( context )
        ? ( isSecurePage ) ? $( secureId, context ) : $( publicId, context )
        : ( isSecurePage ) ? $( secureId ) : $( publicId );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... so I answered my question, but not with anything special. I figured I could just use setInterval and continually check the `page.currentView` property.  And instead of storing it continually, it will always be undefined except for when `page.waitForViewChange` sets it initially.

Changed my **Global JS** to:

```js
var page = 
{                               
    currentView : undefined,
    intervalId  : undefined,

    init : function () 
    { 
        log( "init() fired" );

        this.currentView = getContentElement( "currentView" ).val();
        log( "current view is [" + this.currentView + "]" );

        if ( this.currentView === "forgotpassword" ) { forgotPassword.init(); }
        else { policyLogon.init(); }

        clearInterval( this.intervalId );
        this.intervalId = undefined;
        this.currentView = undefined;
    },

    waitForViewChange : function ( viewToWaitFor ) 
    { 
        log ( "waitForViewChange() fired" );

        this.currentView = getContentElement( "currentView" ).val();
        if ( this.currentView === viewToWaitFor ) { this.init(); }          
    }
};
```

Then in my **Policy Logon View JS** I changed the `forgotPasswordLink.click` event to:

```js
this.forgotPasswordLink.on
(
    "click", 

    function () 
    {     
        page.intervalId = setInterval
        ( 
            'page.waitForViewChange( "forgotpassword" )',
            300 
        ); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the page.init() straightaway , you should bind it to the onLoad even of the body.

`$(document).ready() { page.init() }`

At this time, the DOM has been returned from the server and the `ActiveIndexItem` has also been set.

Comment: All of my JS files are referenced in right before the closing body tag and therefore they don't need to be wrapped in $(document).ready.  However, something else I should mention is that we are using UpdatePanels with Partial PostBacks, so JS never gets refreshed, hence why I need to know when the PostBack returns so that I can fire the correct `init()` myself.

Comment: So basically what you need is to fire some Javascript once the Ajax request (through UpdatePanel) is returned. Take a look at `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method. It allows you to register a Javascript function to be called once the request is completed. Take a look at this question too > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412120/call-a-javascript-function-after-updatepanel-postback-issue

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that.  I don't want to do that.  I want to achieve this in jQuery, if possible.

Comment: I am not too sure that's possible because the requests are being done by UpdatePanel behind the hood. If you make your Ajax requests through jQuery then you have a onSuccess callback function to run your code in but as UpdatePanel is initiating the request under the hood, I don't see any other way to hack into it and run your own code when it completes the return.